# Excel Formula to COUNT and add 2 different values in a cell range.

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

How do I write a formula that will look at a range of cells in a column (Column D = "Region"), then count the number of cells that contain the word North and also the cells that contain the word South, then return a value for the total number of both  (i.e. North(4)"+"South(3)=7)? It's like Sorting, but using a formula or a function.

Comment: Add two COUNTIF() using wildcards?

Comment: Thanks Scott, but please provide an example. What I tried did not work. Also, what should I use as the "Criteria"? Remember I'm trying to get the total number of two different regions. @Hello Fishy

Comment: Is North written alone  in the cell or combined in a string?

Comment: It is combined? and you want the result North(4) + South(3)?

Comment: In that case you need to count "NorthSouth"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can use:

```
="North (" & COUNTIF(D2:D15,"*"&"North"&"*") &")+" &"South ("& COUNTIF(D2:D15,"*" &"South"&"*")&")"
```

The result will be:
North (6)+South (5)
If you only need the Sum:

```
=COUNTIF(D2:D15,"*"&"North"&"*")+COUNTIF(D2:D15,"*" &"South"&"*")
```

Where D2:D15 is the reference of the Column Region modify it to correspond to your Data
"*"&"North"&"*" to find North wherever its place in the string

Comment: Got it. The second formula worked fine and will help me workout what I'm trying to do. Thanks